Как зациклить программу что бы она повторялась при вводе нужного символа?
#include iostream 

int main() 
{ 
char name;  
int age;  
double height;  
char s;  
int menu;  

printf("Введите возраст: "); 
scanf("%d", &age); 

printf("Введите рост: "); 
scanf("%lf", &height); 

printf("Введите пол(M/F): "); 
scanf(" %c", &s); 

printf("Введите своё имя: "); 
scanf(" %c", &name); 

printf("Нажмите: \n [1] - показать Вывод \n [2] - Начать заново \n [3] - Сменить имя \n [4] - закончить"); 
scanf("%d", &menu); 

if(menu == 1) 
{ 
printf("ваше имя\t\t->\t%c\nваш возраст\t->\t%d\nваш рост\t->\t%lf\nваш пол\t\t->\t%c", name, age, height,s); 
} 

else if(menu == 2) 
{ 
main(); 
} 

else if(menu == 3) 
{ 
printf("Введите имя заново: "); 
scanf(" %c", &name); 

printf("ваше имя\t\t->\t%c\nваш возраст\t->\t%d\nваш рост\t->\t%lf\nваш пол\t\t->\t%c", name, age, height,s);
} 
return 0; 
}

(мне нужно что бы появлялась менюшка из 4 пунктов,  далее при вводе 2 анкету можно было ввести по новой и при вводе 4, прога заканчивалась)
я ток начал с этим разбираться и чо то туплю

Замените рекурсию (кстати, main() нельзя вызывать рекурсивно) циклом.
